# Merging huge dataframes in chunks

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two huge dataframes.
Both dataframes are of the following format (example):

```
chr5    1
chr1    250164
chr1    250169
chr1    11467
chr1    250199
```

And I simply want to accomplish a merge on both columns (intersection not union).

But in this case it is more complex than just merging both files with pandas `merge`.
Since both files can be huge (more than 100GB) I read them in chunks in the following manner:

```
pileup_df = pd.read_csv(pileup, '\t', header=None, chunksize=size)
lists_df = pd.read_csv(sorted_lists, '\t', header=None, chunksize=size)

    for iter, (pileup_chunk, lists_chunk) in enumerate(zip(pileup_df, lists_df)):

        intersection = pd.merge(pileup_chunk, lists_chunk, on=[0, 1])
        intersection.columns = [i for i in range(len(intersection.columns))]
    
        if iter == 0:
            intersection.to_csv(output, header=None, index=None, sep='\t')
        else:
            intersection.to_csv(output, mode='a', header=None, index=None, sep='\t')

        del intersection
```

To explain my problem I am going to show an example
if one file's content is :

```
chr5    1
chr1    250164
chr1    250169
chr1    11467
chr1    250199
```

and the second file's content is:

```
chr5    1
chrx    2
chrx    3
chr1    250164
```

Then the output I want to get is

```
chr1    250164
chr5    1
```

But for example, if I pick `chunksize=2` then the output would be

```
chr5    1
```

Bear in mind that sorting the files won't solve this problem too.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Regarding memory problems-I tried to use dask too and still I needed more than one chunk to read these files without memory errors.

Comment: Doesn't dask support out of core joins?

Comment: @anon01 I didn't dig into dask that much - simply tried to read the dataframes and perform merge.
Either way it failed during the reading of the file.
Could you elaborate on what are core joins and how it could help solve this problem?

Comment: one of dask's main features is the ability to operate on dataframes directly from disk rather than reading them into memory

Comment: @anon01 And this feature is the default when reading from file? or I should specify some arguments or use specific functions?
I remember trying to just use the matching function to `read_csv` from pandas and it failed because of `MemoryError`

Comment: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-joins.html

Comment: From dask docs about partitions: "Internally, a Dask DataFrame is split into many partitions, where each partition is one Pandas DataFrame. These DataFrames are split vertically along the index." - doesn't it mean that the problem I described will persist?